# How can i access the jqueryUI theme i generated through themeroller to use on my website?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Basically how do i use themeroller styles?

Step 1 - to - actually seeing the styles on my page of choice.

Here's the html im currently using to try to access the tabs

```
<?php if (isset($user_number)){ ?>

<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

<title> Wahalu - Dashboard </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wahalu/css/style.css"/>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/wahalu/assets/images/icon/favicon.ico">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/wahalu/jquery/jquery.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/wahalu/jquery/script.js">
</script>

<link type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wahalu/jquery/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="/wahalu/jquery/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/wahalu/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>

 <meta name="title" content="Wahalu" />
</head> 
<body id="dashboard">
<?php echo $company_name; ?>
<div id="Tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a id='tabs-1' href='#account'><span>Account</span></a></li>
    <li><a id='tabs-2' href='#start_conversation'><span>Start Conversations</span></a></li>
 <li><a id='tabs-3' href='#view_conversation'><span>View Conversations</span></a></li>
 <li><a id='tabs-4' href='#open_tabs'><span>Open Tabs</span></a></li>
 <li><a id='tabs-5' href='#work_room'><span>Work Room</span></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="0">This is the content panel linked to the first tab, it is shown by default.</div>
<div id="1">This content is linked to the second tab and will be shown when its tab is clicked.</div>
</div>

</body> 
</html>

<?php } else {echo "Na na na na na na, your not logged in.";}?>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "access the styling"? Do you mean that you want to use the theme for the rest of your site - elements that are *not* handled by the jQueryUI code?  If so, then I agree with you that it's not well explained at all. I can't really even help much because I'm really not a fan of the Themeroller looks so I just mostly avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean to edit your custom style (which is how this question is worded in my mind) - you only need to open up `jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css` in a text editor of your choice. There is an url inside this file that contains a direct link back to your custom style on the Themeroller site.